# Volley Headers Customs Java Android

Tags: java, android, volley

Haciendo pruebas en mi app noto que los headers de mi app no llegan la servidor ,

cuento con el siguiente metodo

```
private ObjetRequest<BaseRequest> objectRequest;
      objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(1, "", BaseRequest.class, "", new Response.Listener<BaseRequest>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(BaseRequest response) {

                    // response
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Error
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("sessionToken", Globals.getSessionToken());
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return params;
                }
            };
```

En mi clase utilizo

```
`String rq = RequestManager.getPendingPaymentsCollections(numeroTelefonicoOrigen,TYPE,CANTNOTIFICACIONES,filter);

        GenericController gC = new GenericController(true);
        gC.pendingPaymentsCollections(this,rq, new Response.Listener<GetPendingPaymentsCollections>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(GetPendingPaymentsCollections response) {
                if(response.getMessageRS().getErrorCode().compareTo("0")==0) {
                    int cant = response.getMessageRS().getData().size();
                    int iterador = 0;
                    while (iterador < cant) {

                        CobroPendiente aux = new CobroPendiente(response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("DSTPHONE"),
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("AMOUNT"),
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("CURRECY"),
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("CREATIONDATE"),
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("ID"),
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("REFERENCE"),copiaFilter,
                                response.getMessageRS().getData().get(iterador).get("NAME"));
                        items.add(aux);
                        iterador++;
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    AdapterCobrosPendientesListadoCollections adapter = new AdapterCobrosPendientesListadoCollections(BillingListHistory.this, items);
                    lstbillingnotifications.setAdapter(adapter);
                    lstbillingnotifications.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // No se necesita
                        }
                    });

                    String ret= "" ;
                    if(copiaFilter.compareTo(getString(R.string.FiltroPAY))==0){
                        ret = getString(R.string.ListadoHistoryPAY);
                    }
                    if(copiaFilter.compareTo(getString(R.string.FiltroPND))==0){
                        ret = getString(R.string.ListadoHistoryPND);
                    }
                    if(copiaFilter.compareTo(getString(R.string.FiltroDUE))==0){
                        ret = getString(R.string.listadoHistoryDUE);
                    }
                    if(copiaFilter.compareTo(getString(R.string.FiltroRJT))==0){
                        ret = getString(R.string.ListadoHistoryRJT);
                    }

                    if (items.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(BillingListHistory.this,getString(R.string.respuestaListadoVacioHistory) +" "+ ret , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(BillingListHistory.this, response.getMessageRS().getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(BillingListHistory.this, getString(R.string.ErrorServer), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });`
```

el Metodo PendindPaymentsCollections es el siguiente

```
public void pendingPaymentsCollections(final Context context, String request, final Response.Listener<GetPendingPaymentsCollections> listener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    int method = Request.Method.POST;
    String serviceURL = URLLocal;
    String req = "";
    try {
        req = request;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, null);
        objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, GetPendingPaymentsCollections.class, req, listener, errorListener);

        objectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIME_OUT, 0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(objectRequest);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "an exception was thrown", e);
    }
}
```

Pero observando el LOG de mi servidor no me llegan en el header los headers perzonalizados de arriba , intente varias veces en el

> objectRequest = new ObjetRequest(method, serviceURL, GetPendingPaymentsCollections.class, req, listener, errorListener);

meterle los headers pero no los toma , nose la verdad porque es esto cualquier ayuda es bienvenida